# Server being attacked with key exchange attempts. Not being added to ban list by fail2ban

Tags: linux, ssh, security, fail2ban

Looking through the `sshd` logs, there is a remote machine which appears to be attacking my server. here is an example of an entry. It is always the same IP.

May  8 17:57:32 [removed] sshd[99267]: Unable to negotiate with 37.49.226.19 port 42302: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]

I have installed `fail2ban`, but it doesn't seem like it is blocking this IP.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: This seems tightly related to [your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585342/is-my-network-under-attack) -- linking it in.

Comment: @JeffSchaller It is, although I'm got fail2ban working, and it is banning IPs when they fail with password attempts.

Answer (score 6):

Normally fail2ban don't act on these kind of attacks, to make fail2ban act on these, you need to set the mode to aggressive in your jail in /etc/fail2ban/jail.local

like this:

```
[sshd]
 
# To use more aggressive sshd modes set filter parameter "mode" in jail.local:
# normal (default), ddos, extra or aggressive (combines all).
# See "tests/files/logs/sshd" or "filter.d/sshd.conf" for usage example and details.
 
enabled = true
mode   = aggressive
port    = ssh
logpath = %(sshd_log)s
backend = %(sshd_backend)s
```

for more protection you can perm ban persistant attackers with the recidive jail like this:

```
[recidive]
 
enabled = true
logpath  = /var/log/fail2ban.log
banaction = %(banaction_allports)s
bantime  = 1y
findtime = 1d
maxretry = 2
```

References:

https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/pull/1209

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fail2ban